# How to create a gameobject that can move according to the coordinates of player

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to create a bot that can move according to the coordinates of the main player, repeating the whole position of the player.
I could not use movetoward. because I want the gameobject to redo the entire position of the player.
-- many thank.

Comment: you want a bot which follows the player?

Comment: A bot simply needs movetoward.But I need to copy and move, like a snake's tail